# Enlace simbólico entre neovim y vim

Tags: linux, vim, nvim, desarrollo

estoy tratando de realizar un enlace entre mis configuraciones de neovim y vim pero al ejecutar el comando `ln -s (which nvim) /usr/local/bin/vim` me marca el siguiente error
**zsh: unknown file attribute: h**
revise las rutas y al parecer si hay archivos de neovim y vim hay alguna otra cosa que pueda hacer?
como contexto, vi que en un video usaban ese comando para realizar el enlace simbólico y en el transcurso del video usaban el comando vim {nombre del archivo}.vim y al abrirlo ya traía el esquema de color y se podían agregar pligins directos en el archivo de plugins con el comando :PlugInstall cabe destacar que ya también tengo el manejador de plugins pero al abrir el archivo con el comando vim, no se puede ejecutar el comando y no trae nada del esquema de colores si no hasta que lo ejecuto con nvim

Comment: te falta el simbolo de dolar ejemplo `$(which nvim)` adicional puedes hacer un move de los vim!

Comment: ahora si que como suele pasar en programación, ya me dio un error diferente al parecer ya tengo el  archivo peor no recuerdo haberlo creado, este es el error que me muestra la terminal
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/vim': File exists

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Bryro ya se pudo al parecer estaba linkeado a otra ruta solo le quite la ruta y se la agregue a la que necesitaba!